# CROSS JOIN LATERAL vs NOT EXISTS subquery for distance bound checking

Tags: postgis

My dataset consists of several area id's. Each "area id" can have multiple clusters. For each cluster, I want to check if any of the imei's belonging to that "area id" have been in a 20m proximity or not. Specifically, I want to identify clusters where the proximity has been 20 m or greater.

I can think of two ways of doing this, and wanted to know if my understanding is correct that both queries are logically correct ways of going about this task.

**Query 1**

```sql
    clusters_with_coverage AS (
    
        -- Select the cluster_id, convex_hull geometry, and calculate coverage
    
    SELECT
        c.uc_name,
        c.cluster_id,
        c.convex_hull
    FROM
        bfp_clusters_new c
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM campaign_ping cp
            WHERE ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull::geography, cp."geoJson"::geography, 20)
            
            and 
                cp.generatedAt::date between cp.campstart and cp.campend 
            and 
                cp.imei in (SELECT imei 
                            FROM   imei_clustered
                            WHERE imei_clustered.area_id_ = c.areaid_)        
        )
    )

**Query 2**

    clusters_raw as (
    
    SELECT 
           cg.uc_name,
           cg.cluster_id,
           cg.convex_hull         
    FROM   bfp_clusters_new as cg
    
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT routes."generatedAt",
               routes.imei,
               routes.area_id_
        FROM   campaign_ping as routes
        WHERE  st_distance(
                   ST_Transform(routes.geoJson, 4326)::geography ,
                   ST_Transform(cg.convex_hull, 4326)::geography ) > 20
           and 
               routes.generatedAt::date between routes.campstart and routes.campend 
           and 
               routes.imei in (SELECT imei 
                               FROM   imei_clustered
                               WHERE  imei_clustered.area_id_ = cg.areaid_)
        ) routes
    )
```

Comment: Can't you visually validate this to answer your own question?

Comment: both queries will return a result set, so I am not sure which to trust.

Comment: Tip: if you don't know how SQL behaves, try first your complex query using simple samples: here, create a table with 2 polygons (fake clusters) and a table with 3 lines (fake roads) (one within 20m of a fake clusters and 2 further away). Forget anything else from your query (no imei, no transformation, no generatedAt, no casting etc)

Comment: Tip 2: visualize your results and look for clusters that are kept even though they are less than 20m from a road, and look for duplicated clusters.

Comment: Rule of thumb: `LATERAL` if you need **access to the subquery results**, `EXISTS` **if a boolean check is enough** - `EXISTS` short circuits out of execution if its statement finds the first matching result, so it is a lot more performant in its realm of applications. Both iterate over the left side set of records without further restrictions.

Comment: @geozelot - in the EXISTS scenario (query 1), would the conditions other than the "ST_Dwithin" be checked correctly? For each cluster, I want to check the imei's belonging to that "area id" only